# create a screen with Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to switch screen with kivy without a builder or a button. I cannot find something inside the Kivy documentation so I'm trying here.

I've tried different way. First, to create my screen, I use the following class:

```
class LoadingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        self.fontup =  'hollywoodcapital.ttf'
        self.fontdw = 'asseenontv.ttf'
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "TEXT 1", font_size='50sp', font_name = self.fontup))
        self.add_widget(Image(source = 'bckgrndlogo.png'))
        layout.add_widget(Label(text = "TEXT 2", font_size='35sp', font_name = self.fontdw))
        self.add_widget(layout)
```

As you can see, I've try to put a label inside using 'self.add_widget' and 'layout.add_widget'.

After that, to display the screen, I've tried 2 different ways:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sc1 = LoadingScreen(name = 'loadscr')
sm.add_widget(sc1)   
sm.current = 'loadscr'
```

Or

```
sm.switch_to(screens[0])
```

For those 2 methods, I only have one white screen, it seems like it display the screen but not its widget.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example

Comment: posted below, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post a reproducible example, I have to guess.
Try this:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
setattr(sm, 'current', "loadscr")
```

Comment: A reproducible example is posted below

Comment: Tried and it gives me this error: "kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "loadscr"."

Answer (score 0):

I've work on that since my post is one-week-old. As my code is + 500 lines long, I've tried to modify it, I hope it's runnable:

```
# ---------------------------- IMPORTING MODULES -----------------------------
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import subprocess
import sys
import os
import time
    
# ------------------------------ KIVY INTERFACE ------------------------------

class LoadingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoadingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(LoadingLayout())

class VideoScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VideoScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(VideoWindow())

class LoadingLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoadingLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fontup =  'hollywoodcapital.ttf'
        self.fontdw = 'asseenontv.ttf'
        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 3
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Éppen  kapcsolódunk  Magyarországhoz", font_size='50sp', font_name = self.fontup))
        self.add_widget(Image(source = # a png logo))
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Legyen türelemmel...", font_size='35sp', font_name = self.fontdw))

class VideoWindow(Video):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 1
        self.add_widget(Video(source = #video))
        self.state = "play"
        self.options = {'eos':'loop'}
        self.allow_stretch = True
        self.fullscreen = True

class MainWindow(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()

        sc1 = Screen(name = 'loadscr')
        sc1.add_widget(LoadingScreen(name = 'loadscr'))
        sc2 = Screen(name = 'videoscr')
        sc2.add_widget(VideoScreen(name = 'videoscr'))
        
        sm.add_widget(sc1)

        return sm


# ------------------------------- MAIN PROGRAM ------------------------------- 
window = MainWindow()
Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
window.run()
```

With this code, I've the first screen without problem. But now I'm trying to switch to the 2nd screen, without success from now.